# Trouble With Custom Fonts in PDFBox

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

So I'm trying to load a custom font that I can use with PDFBox, but the methods don't seem to be working, even though the font appears to load correctly.

I'm doing:

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
InputStream istream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/FiraMono-Regular.ttf");
PDTrueTypeFont monReg = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, istream);
```

but when I run it I get:

```
java.io.EOFException
```

However using the same InputStream with

```
Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, istream); 
System.out.println(myFont);
```

Gets me the expected output:

```
java.awt.Font[family=Fira Mono,name=Fira Mono,style=plain,size=1]
```

So it appears that the font is being correctly loaded in my project, but I can't feed it into PDFBox.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell what PDFBox version you are using?

Comment: I am using PDFBox version 2.0.3

Comment: I just did this: `PDTrueTypeFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, new URL("https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/firamono/FiraMono-Regular.ttf?raw=true").openStream()); System.out.println(font);` and the output is `PDTrueTypeFont FiraMono-Regular`.

Comment: I tried doing that (and if this works this is a good solution for my needs), but I'm getting a 400 error from the line: `PDTrueTypeFont monReg = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, new URL("https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/firamon‌​o/FiraMono-Regular.t‌​tf?raw=true").openStream());`

Comment: Maybe you're on a corporate network and can't download like this... Then try downloading the font, and then loading it as file, not as a stream. My suspicion is that you have a different file (i.e. not the original one), or a problem with your resources. Btw I'm using JDK8. If the file loading works, then load as a FileInputStream, to slowly approach your actual code...

Comment: Currently I have the .ttf saved in the "resources" folder of my netbeans project. The font seems to load fine from that file as I showed in my question, I can create a Java.FONT object based on it, but trying to do loadTTF(doc, InputStream) gives me the EOFException.

Comment: What I am asking you is to try to call loadTTF with the file parameter, not as a resource stream.

Comment: That does work, doing for example: PDTrueTypeFont monRegBold = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, new File("/Users/Me/Desktop/MyProject/ProjectLibrary/src/main/FontSources/FiraMono-Bold.ttf")) but it is not an acceptable solution because I need this to work when deployed on another platform that would have a completely different filepath for this font. That's why I want to load it as a resource or from the web.

Comment: I got that one to work too - here's what I did (Netbeans ANT project, its different if you use maven): create a resources subdir under src; put the ttf file; code: `InputStream is = FireMono.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/FiraMono-Regular.ttf");
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDTrueTypeFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, is); System.out.println(font.getBoundingBox());` and that worked, output: `[-625.0,-500.0,1192.0,1050.0]`

Comment: My next test if I were you is to copy your input stream into a file, and then check whether the content is the same as the original file. (Yes, it sounds desperate)